# get coordinates array from function into vue mutation

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Can't get my variable coords array into this.updateInformation({}) which becomes a vue mutation. Think this is a javascript question, have tried; let, const and var with no luck. Thanks for the help.

```
 getAddressData: function (addressData, placeResultData, id) {
    this.address = addressData;
    if (addressData !== null) {
      console.log("addressData", addressData); 

      var coords = [addressData.latitude, addressData.longitude]

      console.log("coords", coords)

       this.updateInformation({

        location: coords,

        city: addressData.locality,
        title: this.post.title,
        description: this.post.description,
        images: this.post.images,
        location: this.post.location
      })
    }
  },
```

My console looks likes this:

[STORE MUTATIONS] - UPDATE_INFORMATION: {location: "", city: "Donostia-San Sebastian", title: "sss", description: "ssssssss", images: "341482_317197958332079_1486521504_o.jpg"}

Here is my store mutation:

```
  [UPDATE_INFORMATION] (state, info) {
    console.log('[STORE MUTATIONS] - UPDATE_INFORMATION:', info)
    state.newPost.images = info.images
    state.newPost.title = info.title
    state.newPost.description = info.description
    state.newPost.location = info.location
    state.newPost.city = info.city
  },
```

Comment: Could you paste your mutation code too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if I'm not wrong, you're writing the location field twice:

```
this.updateInformation({

location: coords, //location assigned once

city: addressData.locality,
title: this.post.title,
description: this.post.description,
images: this.post.images,
location: this.post.location // location assigned the second time
})
```

So the field that arrives to your mutation is not the `coord` variable, is `this.post.location`. I believe you forgot to delete the latter assignation.